# What is the name of this inequality of sigma and product?

Tags: linear-algebra, measure-theory, inequality

Does this inequality have a name so I could search for it's prove?

$$for \sum_{i=1}^{n} t_i=1 $$
We have:
$$
    (x_1^{t_1})  ... (x_n^{t_n}) <= (t_1x_1) +...+ (t_nx_n)
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I did some more searches and apparently this is a form of AM–GM inequality. So it can be proved by Jensen's inequality.